# Why there is no stack overflow while using asynchronous operations?

Tags: c++11, asynchronous, recursion, boost-asio

I'm using [Boost.Asio](http://think-async.com/) for learning asynchronic operations. After reading many articles about this concept I'm still confused why this piece of code which is part of C++11 Examples from Asio Docs isn't making stack overflow? I just can't imagine the flow of the code in this place. It looks recursive so much, because `do_accept();` calls itself again and again... I can imagine that the stack works for 20 clients, but for 2 000 clients? I thought that for Asynchronous operations it is more clear to place `acceptor_.async_accept()` within a loop and without recursive call inside it. Would it work the same?

Class member `call_nr` is added by me for testing purposes.

The code:

```
class server
{
public:
    server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port)
        : acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)),
        socket_(io_service), call_nr(0)
    {
        do_accept();
    }

private:
    void do_accept()
    {
        acceptor_.async_accept(socket_,
            [this](boost::system::error_code ec) // lambda equation
        {
            using namespace std;
            cout << "Call nr " << (++call_nr) << endl;
            if (!ec)
            {
                std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket_))->start();
            }

            do_accept();
        });
    }

    int call_nr;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
    tcp::socket socket_;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the lambda expression you're creating is getting saved as a functor and stored in a data structure associated with the `io_service` object.

When you call async_accept, that call returns immediately. It doesn't create a new stack frame (semantically. Technically, it does, but it only exists for a few fractions of a millisecond)

When the lambda expression eventually gets called, it'll be on the stack of any associated threads with the `io_service`, not the original stack.

Answer (score 3):

Callbacks != recursive pattern.

behind the scens , Boost.Asio works with some polling objects that notifies the program that some Asynchronous IO operation is complete.
on windows, we are talking about *IO Completion Port*
on Linux , we are talkig about *epoll*.

when async IO action is complete, the polling object polls some control block which containes details about the IO action which is done.
on windows we are talking about `OVERLAPPED` structure.
on Linux, we are talking abot `aiocb` structure.

Boost.Asio (and other platforms, like libuv/node.js, .Net, Java etc.) inherit from that control block and adding other stuff to it. Boost.Asio adds callbacks objects.

So when the polling object polls the control blocks, Boost.Asio pulls the callback and runs it. it may launch another async IO action with another callback, but when that original callback is *done* the stack returns to the caller. that function doesn't stay for long - even if another IO is launched the functions moves on to completion.

A flow may look like this:

```
1) execute function A which reads file async
2) an asynchonous IO action is launched with a callback B 
3) A continues to execute. it does not block since this is an async IO action
4) A finiehs to run and returns to the caller
5) some time later , the async IO finishes
6) IOCP/epoll polls the control block
7) the IOCP/epoll thread pulls callback B and execute it
8) callback B launches a new async IO action with callback C
9) B continues to execute, since the async IO doesn't block
10) B finished to run and returns to the caller
11) some time later, the Async IO is finished ... and so one
```

for more details, read about the *reactor pattern*

Comment: So all this comes to adding functors to some list managed by io_service which executes them in FIFO order? And every functor calls himself again to maintain its existence in the queue? Am i at least close to it now?

Comment: not exactly. when an IO action is done - you get the results + the callback. that callback in its turn can launch new IO again. there is no FIFO here. whatever IO action is done first is the first to be poll by the IOCP/epoll. and that callback is deleted after it done.

Comment: for example, it's like taking a worker man, stick a paper on its back and send him to do some nasty work. when he's back saying "i'm done" you re-read the paper, and do whatever the paper says. then you throw away the paper. the paper may tell you to attach new paper to the worker and send him again

Comment: But meanwhile a worker is doing nasty work i can talk with another worker, is that true?

Comment: yes, the worker(s) is the OS. in meantime you can read other papers / do other stuff and send other workers. this is why async IO is so scalable

Answer (score 1):

Only synchronous calls grow the stack.

With `acceptor_.async_accept` you're passing in a callback function that you're asking the system to call *later*.

Importantly, it does not get called immediately, and therefore not from where you are on the stack.

If you put a breakpoint in your lambda function and examine its stack, you'll notice that it gets called from somewhere else (inside the code implementing `acceptor_`).

Therefore, when this runs *later* and calls `do_accept` again, it is with that new stack.

This isn't technically recursion in the traditional sense. It is an asynchronous "loop" only in the sense that it will keep calling the function over and over, but every time from a point later in time, and no stack accumulation is needed to accomplish this, so it can go on forever.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm in no way an expert of Boost.Asio.**

The control flow is as follow:

1. `do_accept` is called.
2. `acceptor_.async_accept` is called with a *lambda*, let's call it *L*.
3. `acceptor_.async_accept` returns **with no call** to *L*.
4. `do_accept` returns.

Upon a connection request, this happen

1. *L* is called.
2. `do_accept` is called again. Repeat from 1.

As you see the second call to  `do_accept` happen when the previous one is already finished.

If `acceptor_.async_accept` called *L* before returning, you would indeed have a recursion that could lead to a stack overflow.

You should look at the source of `acceptor_.async_accept`, you should see that even if a connection request happen during the execution of `acceptor_.async_accept`, it will not be processed by *L*.
That is internally there is a synchronization mechanism between `acceptor_.async_accept` and the code that call *L*.